# Receiving Error: NameError: name 'size_cost' is not define

Tags: python-3.x

I am having a bit of issues running my code. I keep getting a NameError: name 'size_cost' is not define.

A little background about my code/what I am trying to do. I am trying to create a program that runs through the terminal on VSCODE that has the user enter their pizza size they want and then return a price that the size is associated with in the dictionary called 'size_cost'.

I bleieve my issue is with the location of the dictionary(size_cost) or with my class/functions I am trying to create.

Here is the code I am running:

```
class PizzaOrderingSys:
    size_cost = {
'small': 9.75,
'large': 12.23,
'extra large': 13.80,
'party size': 26.50
}
    pizza_size_order = []
    available_toppings = ['Anchovies', 'Artichoke Hearts', 'Bacon', 'Basil (Fresh)', 'Bell Peppers', 'Black Olives', 'Chicken', 'Extra Cheese',
'Green Chiles', 'Green Olives','Pepperoni', 'Ground Beef', 'Jalapenos', 'Mushrooms']
    customer_requested_toppings = []
    number_of_toppings = 0

def __init__(self, size, toppings):
self.size = size
self.toppings= toppings

def shop_title():
print("Hello and thank you for choosing The Pizza Pie Place! \nBegin your order by telling us what size of pizza you would like.")
print("After you have chosen your pizza size you will pick your toppings")
return None
def size_order():
print('\n12 inch - Small ($9.75 + Tax), 14 inch- Large ($12.30 + Tax), 16 inch- Extra Large ($13.80 + Tax), 24 inch Party Pizza($26.50 + Tax)')
print('\tWhat size pizza do you want?')
        user_size = input('')
print(f'Your {user_size} pizza will cost ${size_cost[user_size] }')
        list_pizza =  size_cost[user_size]
        pizza_size_order.append(list_pizza)

    order_1 = shop_title()
    order_1= size_order()
```

So what I am asking is; Why do I keep getting this error message? Is it because of where my dictionary is located? or am I having issues with my class/functions and if so what is wrong with them?

I am fairly new to the coding world so thought I would start working with some fundamental elements of python.

ANY advice would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: "Is it because of where my dictionary is located?" - yes. `size_cost` in the `size_order` function refers to a _local_ variable called `size_cost`, but this variable doesn't exist.

Comment: Would that dictionary need to placed in the size_order function? Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: If `size_order` is meant to be a method of the `PizzaOrderingSys` class, it should be defined as `def size_order(self):` and refer to `size_cost` as `self.size_cost`. See [Python's tutorial on classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

As ForceBru pointed out, size_cost does not exist in the function as it is a class variable. However, what I fail to understand is how you are initialising your class? Your second function (are they inside the class? Unclear to see as there are no indentations) asks for a size from the user, but that size is passed on when you initialise the class? To answer your question: yes, you can put the dictionary inside the function. However, if other class methods need to be able to access it, I think you'd be better of having it as a class variable, which is accessible through a class instance.

As a minimal example:

```
class PizzaOrderingSys:
    size_cost = {
    'small': 9.75,
    'large': 12.23,
    'extra large': 13.80,
    'party size': 26.50
    }
    pizza_size_order = []
    available_toppings = ['Anchovies', 'Artichoke Hearts', 'Bacon', 'Basil (Fresh)', 'Bell Peppers', 'Black Olives', 'Chicken', 'Extra Cheese',
    'Green Chiles', 'Green Olives','Pepperoni', 'Ground Beef', 'Jalapenos', 'Mushrooms']
    customer_requested_toppings = []
    number_of_toppings = 0

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def my_function(self, string):
        self.cost = self.size_cost[string]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    order_1 = PizzaOrderingSys()
    order_1.my_function('small')
    print(order_1.cost)
```

Comment: Hey Steven, thanks for the assistance. There were a view typos when I pasted the code(didn't transfer over very well). They were supposed to be outside of the code. I will end up accessing the dictionary to provide total cost of the user's order, so I try it as a class variable. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Hi Chris, you're welcome. Okay, if you are writing this as a class, I would suggest that your put those functions inside the class as well (see ForceBru's answer). Otherwise, it does not make sense to use a class here.